# Error on Gatsby when adding a script in the body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

When I'm trying to add a script on the body of Gatsby I've added the following code into the file called gatsby-ssr.js

```
const React = require("react")

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
    setPostBodyComponents([
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        {`
        (function() {
          var envolveChatWidgetScript = document.createElement('script');
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute('data-wg-publisher', '222222');
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute('data-wg-campaign', '333333');
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://widget.envolvetech.com/static/js/app.js');
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute('data-identifier', 'my_identifier');
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute('data-backend', 'https://bot-dot-envolvetech-001.appspot.com');
          document.body.appendChild(envolveChatWidgetScript);
          })();
          `}
          </script>
    ]);
};
```

but then somehow what it's actually in the mark up is this

```
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
        (function() {
          var envolveChatWidgetScript = document.createElement(&#x27;script&#x27;);
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute(&#x27;data-wg-publisher&#x27;, &#x27;222222&#x27;);
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute(&#x27;data-wg-campaign&#x27;, &#x27;3333333&#x27;);
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute(&#x27;src&#x27;, &#x27;https://widget.envolvetech.com/static/js/app.js&#x27;);
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute(&#x27;data-identifier&#x27;, &#x27;my_identifier#x27;);
          envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute(&#x27;data-backend&#x27;, &#x27;https://bot-dot-envolvetech-001.appspot.com&#x27;);
          document.body.appendChild(envolveChatWidgetScript);
          })();
          </script>
```

any ideas why it gets translated into that ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading a few GH threads I found out that adding the script using dangerouslySetInnerHTML actually works
[https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11108](https:///https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/11108)

```
const React = require("react")

exports.onRenderBody = ({ setPostBodyComponents }) => {
    setPostBodyComponents([
        <script
     dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html:`
        (function() {
            var envolveChatWidgetScript = document.createElement("script");
            envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute("data-wg-publisher", "222222");
            envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute("data-wg-campaign", "333333");
            envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute("src","https://widget.envolvetech.com/static/js/app.js");
            envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute("data-identifier", "my_identifier");
            envolveChatWidgetScript.setAttribute("data-backend", "https://bot-dot-envolvetech-001.appspot.com");
            document.body.appendChild(envolveChatWidgetScript);
            })();
     `
     }}
     />,
    ]);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [customizing the `html.js`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/custom-html/)?

Run:

```
cp .cache/default-html.js src/html.js
```

Or manually copy the `default-html.js` (placed inside `.cache`) to `/src`

And place your script there.

When Gatsby builds your site if there's a `html.js` inside `/src`, it will use it as a boilerplate for your site

In the html.js you'll see all the `postBodyComponents`, `onPreRenderHTML` and other customizing APIs. However, in this case, you'll be inserting the raw script instead of allowing Gatsby to parse it.

Comment: This didn't work for me but I still think it's a useful answer, thanks ! So somehow my building was falling adding the html.js but thanks anyway.